# Herencia en Laravel

Tags: php, poo

Resulta que vengo de aprender PHP puro y en los proyectos que hice tenia un modelo en el que tenia una superclase usuario con los atributos en comun que heredaban las clases hijas.
Pero ahora que estoy descubriendo Laravel veo que cada clase extiende de Model y por cada una genera una tabla en la base de datos.
Tambien veo que al extender Model no es posible extender la superclase ya que php no permite herencia multiple e implementarlo como una interface no es la solucion.

Alguien sabe como implementar un modelo de este tipo?
Gracias.

Comment: Como consejo, si piensas utilizar un framework, tú debes adaptarte a cómo trabaja el framework, no adaptar el framework a ti.

Comment: Es que es como la confusion que tengo de no saber si dado a que varias clases tienen los mismos atributos, sea correcto ponerlos en cada una de estas y no hacer una superclase.

Comment: Como ya indicaron, las solucion es utilizar trait, lo cual no es de laravel sino de php asi que si estabas aprendiendo POO en php los trait no deberian de ser algo extraño para ti.

Comment: Vale, entiendo y agradezco la ayuda que me han dado